# Automatically enter SVN URL into svn info

Tags: svn

I want to write a file into each of my releases with the information obtained from `svn info`. The problem is that at the moment the build-script executes the command it doesn't know what the SVN URL is. If I just use

```
svn info
```

then the information is not about the latest revision in the repository but about the latest revision of the current directory (which may differ from what I actually want).

So the question is: Is there a way to automatically get the SVN URL of the current working copy to be able to use svn info like this:

```
svn info http://path_to_repostiory/
```

Comment: Why would you want info on the repository itself as opposed to the version of the code you pulled down and compiled?

Comment: Maybe it wasn't really clear: svn info gets me 533 (revision of current directory) - svn info http://path_to_repository gets me 672 which is the revision of the file that was checked in last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of. You can use something like:

```
svn info `svn info | grep URL | cut -f2 -d' '`
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what OS you're using.  On windows, the following works:

`for /f %a in ('"svn info | grep URL | sed -e 's/^URL: //'"') do svn info %a`

Comment: Then (from memory, I don't have a box handy to test), you'd want svn info \`svn info | grep URL | sed -e 's/^URL: //'\`